# Filtrar y sumar en un array de Objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo este array de objetos y necesito filtrar por el id y sumar las horas de cada uno.

```
const empleados = [
  {id: '12345', nombre: 'Pedro', horas: 5},
  {id: '1234', nombre: 'Jose', horas: 4},
  {id: '123', nombre: 'Juan', horas: 7},
  {id: '12345', nombre: 'Pedro', horas: 5},
  {id: '1234', nombre: 'Jose', horas: 4}
];
```

El resultado debería ser

```
[ { id: '123', nombre: 'Juan', horas: 7 }, 
  { id: '1234', nombre: 'Jose', horas: 8 }, 
  { id: '12345', nombre: 'Pedro', horas: 10 } ]
```

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco-.

Comment: ``No puedo usar ni librerias ni expersiones regulares.`` Eso me hace entender que es un ejercicio que te dan para que VOS resuelvas. En este sitio la idea no es hacerle la tarea a los estudiantes, la idea es que vos lo intentes y aca te ayudemos con lo que no te sale. Podrias agregar lo que has intentado?

Comment: Lo que yo haría es:

 - Ordenarlos de menor a mayor
 - Si dos elementos contiguos son iguales, entonces lo suma. Puede ser con reduce
 - Guardarlos en un array con datos semejantes

Veo que es una tarea o para una entrevista, así que no le resuelvo ya que la idea es que desarrolle la lógica.

Comment: Debes mostrar lo que intentaste para que la pregunta sea mejor aceptada en este sitio. Aquí intentamos ayudar cuando el que pregunta se encalla, pero debe mostrar algún intento para resolver su problema, y tu tan solo has hecho un planteamiento. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y cómo deben ser las preguntas para que tengan mejor aceptación y recibas mejores respuestas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Prueba esta solución a ver que tal te va!

```
const empleados = [
  {id: '12345', nombre: 'Pedro', horas: 5},
  {id: '1234', nombre: 'Jose', horas: 4},
  {id: '123', nombre: 'Juan', horas: 7},
  {id: '12345', nombre: 'Pedro', horas: 5},
  {id: '1234', nombre: 'Jose', horas: 4}
];

const results = []

empleados.forEach(empleado => {
    const empleadoIndex = results.findIndex(result => result.id === empleado.id)
    if (empleadoIndex > -1) {
        results[empleadoIndex].horas += empleado.horas
    } else {
        results.push(empleado)
    }
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sea de ayuda!